# Neo4j Cypher Query "NOT IN" doesnt work, "IN" works

Tags: spring, neo4j, cypher

I try to create a cypher-query in my Java-Spring-Application which should answer the question "give all employees who did not create a item in item.nameList":

```
@Query("START it=node:__types__(className = 'de.my.domain.ItemCl') MATCH empl-[r:CREATE]->it WHERE (it.name NOT IN ({0})) RETURN DISTINCT empl")
List<Employee> findAllEmployeesWhoNeverCreatedItemFromItemNameList(List<String> itemNameList);
```

This query gives an "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException" and marks the "NOT" as failure.

If I try the same query without NOT ("give all employees who did create a item in item.nameList", the query does what it should.

In this thread Peter Neubauer told that this "NOT IN" exists in cypher: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/_PehVUfGaIA

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`NOT` is a negation, so you have to do it like this:

```
WHERE NOT(it.name IN({0}))
```

Comment: Thank you, I misunderstood the NOT.
I tested it and i get from WHERE NOT(it.name IN({0})) and WHERE (it.name IN({0})) the same results. Very confusing.